# SignalR groups in redis backplane

Tags: signalr, signalr-backplane

Making SignalR work with Redis backplane is as simple as adding `AddStackExchangeRedis("localhost:6379");` to `AddSignalR` in `Startup.cs`.

So when I add a connection to a group in SignalR using `this.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionId, groupName);`, Redis will also keep track of my group, right?

Is it possible to know when a new group is added to Redis or removed? An event or something? Or is it possible to programmatically check if a group exists? I'm Redis newbie.

Comment: good question Joana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want. You can start reading this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-3.1) about Redis & SignalR.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed SignalR syncs its groups with Redis by adding channels, so I could check if a group exists or not by checking the channels.

And in Redis I can check that by running `pubsub channels`